# Can refrigerator pickles be processed?

Tags: refrigerator, canning, pickles

I have a made refrigerator pickles and put them in jars with lids sealed. Can I now process them?

Comment: What do you mean by process?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SA! Have a look at the [Tour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Center](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help), especially the information on [how to ask a good question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) when you get a chance.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, no. The reason recipes get advertised as "refrigerator pickles" is that they don't fulfill the requirements for being shelf-stable after canning. If you want shelf-stable pickles, follow a standard recipe which includes canning instructions, not a recipe for refrigerator pickles.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the brine. If you were forced to create a refrigerator pickle, say, because you ran out of jar's so you stashed it in the fridge, there's nothing to say you can't go back, drain and heat that brine, jar and pour over the vegetable, and process the next day if it's the right acidity.

It is a very low acid straight fridge pickle you bought at the store, or one not appropriate to process, the answer is no, unless you change the brine. It's all still food after all, but I'd keep it to home made only.
It's just being held... Many recipes call for an overnight soak in the fridge to crisp them anyway.